# Get cart item key when a product is added to cart via Ajax in WooCommerce

Tags: ajax, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, product

I added plus minus quantity buttons with add to cart button. While plus is working fine with ajax and add_to_cart button is also working fine. However the problem is I need `cart_item_key` at the same time with ajax `add_to_cart` so user can minus the quantity of product from cart.

When I refresh page then minus button also work for already added products in cart but i don't want to refresh the page.

I just tried something like this but not working.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments', 'custom_function');
function custom_function($fragments){ 
    global $woocommerce; 
    ob_start(); ?> 
    <a class="cart-contents" href="<?php echo WC()->cart->get_cart_url(); ?>" title="<?php _e( 'View your shopping cart' ); ?>"> 
        <?php foreach ( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
            echo $cart_item_key; 
        } ?> 
    </a> 
    <?php $fragments['a.cart-contents'] = ob_get_clean(); 
    return $fragments; 
}
```

If any one can help ?

Thank You

Comment: i just tried something like this but not working

add_filter('woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments',  'custom_function');
function custom_function($fragments){
 
global $woocommerce;
ob_start(); 
?>
 <a class="cart-contents" href="<?php echo WC()->cart->get_cart_url(); ?>" title="<?php _e( 'View your shopping cart' ); ?>">
        <?php foreach ( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
   echo  $cart_item_key;
   } ?>
    </a>
<?php 
 $fragments['a.cart-contents'] = ob_get_clean();
    return $fragments;
}

Comment: Actually i added plus minus button with add to cart, now problem is plus working with ajax but minus not working at the same time, i have to reload page for working minus . are you getting my point?

i want to get product item key at the time with ajax add to cart so i can minus product with the same time

and i have added plus minus button on category page, product detail page, every where with add to cart .

the problem is only i have to refresh for get key of current added product into cart

i need to work all three button (addtocart, plus, minus ) with ajax

Comment: Please **update your question** instead *(the little **"edit"** text button under question tags)*, **taking your time** to clarify it and adding **all the related code**, as without it nobody will be able to really help you.

Answer (score 1):

Like this ?

```
function woocommerce_header_add_to_cart_fragment( $fragments ) {
    global $woocommerce;
    $arr = [];
    foreach ( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
        $arr[$cart_item_key] = $cart_item['product_id'];
    }

    ob_start();

    get_template_part('template-parts/fooooo');

    $fragments['#header-cart-data'] = ob_get_clean();
    $fragments['#updated_ajax_cart'] = $arr;

    return $fragments;
}
```